# How to split csv into 2 dataframe with the condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My idea is seperate both of the "String" then convert both dataframe into same datetime format. I try the code

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['date'] = data['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but there are some error on the output. The 13/02/2020 will become 2020-02-13 that is what i want. But the 12/02/2020 will become 2020-12-02.

My dataframe have 2 type of date format. Which is YYYY-MM-DD and DD/MM/YYYY.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gyo8.png)

I need to **split** it into 2 dataframe, all the row that have the date **YYYY-MM-DD** into the **df1**.

The data type is object.

All all the row that have the date **DD/MM/YYYY** into the **df2**.

Anyone know how to code it?

Comment: You need also convert it to datetimes?

Comment: My idea is seperate both of the "String" then convert both dataframe into same datetime format.  I try the code `data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`,`data['date'] = data['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, but there are some error on the output. The 13/02/2020 will become 2020-02-13 that is what i want. But the 12/02/2020 will become 2020-12-02.

Comment: I got you, added solution in `EDIT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dont need convert to datetimes use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['date'].str.contains('-')
df1 = df[mask].copy()
df2 = df[~mask].copy()
```

If need datetimes you can use parameter `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for missing values if not matching format, so last remove missing values:

```
df1 = (df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
        .dropna(subset=['date']))

df2 = (df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
         .dropna(subset=['date']))
```

EDIT: If need output column filled by correct datetimes you can replace missing values by another `Series` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = date1.fillna(date2)
```

Comment: The EDIT (second) code is the correct code. Thank you. `date1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = date1.fillna(date2)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fact that the separation is different to find the dates.

If your dataframe is in this format:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,2,2,3,3], 
   "Date": ["30/8/2020","30/8/2021","30/8/2022","2019-10-24","2019-10-25","2020-10-24"] })
```

With either "-" or "/" to separate the data

you can use a function that finds this element and apply it to the date column:

```
   def find(string):
       if string.find('/')==2:
     return True 
       else:
     return False

   df[df['date'].apply(find)]
```